# Как сделать чтобы бот реагировал на неизвестные команды. Телеграм python

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужно что бы бот на сообщения по типу "**ghhbsdjkhjfksdjk**" реагировал "*Не знаю такой команды*!".
Пробовал

```
else:   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Извините, я Вас не понимаю")
```

получаю синтаксическую ошибку. Может что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    global keyId
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, Звездная пыль!')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Прощай, Звездная пыль!')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'дай':
        if keyId == '0':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Поживится нечем')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'НЕ ДАМ!')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я тебя не понимаю...')
```

Учтите, что от этого кода, бот будет реагировать на каждый текст...

Comment: Спасибо! Но где "я тебя не понимаю" у меня сработало когда я заменил document на message

Comment: Ну и хорошо... главное что суть уловили. )